# Character "&" in OWL ontology

Tags: python, xml, special-characters, owl, ampersand

I am creating a Python module that modifies an OWL ontology and I have this word: "CheapB&B"

But the execution returns the following error:

> The reference to entity "B" must end with the delimiter ';'

I tried replace `&` with `&amp;` and I no longer have the error, but the result is not `CheapB&B` but only `B`.

How to solve?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: I assume you mean in an XML based encoding of the ontology (RDF/XML encoding of RDF mapping of OWL ontology, or OWL/XML).  It's expected that the serialization will have to escape characters that must be escaped in that serialization.